# Pivot the values in one column with a key value in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I want to transform the `Program` column into as many new columns as there are values in the data (in the example, three) then consolidate the rows based on the `ID` column:

```
ID          Program
50000001    English Language Learner (ELL)
50000001    Free and Reduced Lunch (FRL)
50000002    English Language Learner (ELL)
50000002    Free and Reduced Lunch (FRL)
50000002    Special Education (SPED)
50000003    Special Education (SPED)
```

This is what I want:

```
ID          English Language Learner (ELL)  Free and Reduced Lunch (FRL)    Special Education (SPED)
50000001    English Language Learner (ELL)  Free and Reduced Lunch (FRL)
50000002    English Language Learner (ELL)  Free and Reduced Lunch (FRL)    Special Education (SPED)
50000003                                                                    Special Education (SPED)
```

I did this a long ago with either Excel directly, or using KUTOOLS, but don't remember how.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can create the row and column labels as unique lists and that you add a column to "what I have" that concatenates these by row (say with something like `=A2&B2`) and that you name this `Clist`, then the following may serve at the intersection of the first numeric ID with the first Program (being B2 since assumed to be in a different sheet), copied across and down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH($A2&B$1,Clist,0)>0,B$1,),"")
```